# Cannot remove entity which is target of @OneToOne relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have following entities with @OneToOne relation:

```
@Entity
public static class EntityChild extends BaseEntity {
    //Id from superclass
}

@Entity
public static class EntityParent extends BaseEntity {

    //Id from superclass

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
    private EntityChild child;

    //child getter/setter
}
```

Now following test doesn't pass:

```
EntityParent parent = new EntityParent();
em.persist(parent);
em.flush();

EntityChild child = new EntityChild();
parent.setChild(child);
em.persist(parent);
em.flush();

em.remove(parent.getChild());
em.flush();
```

It throws exception on the last line, with flush(). The exception is `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [my.package.EntityChild#<null>]`

Why can't I delete this entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the association between parent and child first, otherwise Hibernate tries to persist the child again due to `cascade = ALL`:

```
EntityChild c = parent.getChild();
parent.setChild(null);
em.remove(c);
em.flush();
```

**Update:**

Here are excerpts from the [JPA specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) related to this behaviour. Exception is thrown due to conflict between [1] and [2] during `flush()` (though I can't find where it's specified):

> The semantics of the **flush** operation, applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
>
>   - **For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been
>       annotated with the `cascade` element value `cascade=PERSIST` or `cascade=ALL`, the persist operation is applied to Y.**
>   - For any entity Y referenced by a relationship from X, where the relationship to Y has
>       not been annotated with the `cascade` element value `cascade=PERSIST` or `cascade=
>       ALL`:
>
>     - If Y is new or removed, an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown
>         by the flush operation (and the transaction marked for rollback) or the transaction
>         commit will fail.
>     - If Y is detached, the semantics depend upon the ownership of the relationship.
>         If X owns the relationship, any changes to the relationship are synchronized
>         with the database; otherwise, if Y owns the relationships, the behavior
>         is undefined.
> - **If X is a removed entity, it is removed from the database. No cascade options are relevant. <--------------- [1]**

---

> The semantics of the **persist**
>   operation, applied to an entity X are
>   as follows:
>
> - If X is a new entity, it
>     becomes managed. The entity X will be
>     entered into the database at or before
>     transaction commit or as a result of
>     the flush operation.
> - If X is a
>     preexisting managed entity, it is
>     ignored by the persist operation.
>     However, the persist operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by X,
>     if the relationships from X to these
>     other entities are annotated with the
>     `cascade=PERSIST` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation element value or specified
>     with the equivalent XML descriptor
>     element.
> - **If X is a removed entity,
>     it becomes managed. <--------------- [2]**
> - If X is a
>     detached object, the
>     `EntityExistsException` may be thrown
>     when the persist operation is invoked,
>     or the `EntityExistsException` or
>     another `PersistenceException` may be
>     thrown at flush or commit time.
> - For
>     all entities Y referenced by a
>     relationship from X, if the
>     relationship to Y has been annotated
>     with the cascade element value
>     `cascade=PERSIST` or `cascade=ALL`, the
>     persist operation is applied to Y.

Comment: It works, thanks @axtavt ! However, I'd like to fully understand it. When I remove child and then flush, does em look at relations to this child, finds that parent has relation, and merges parent? And then it's clear, in parent there is child, so it tries to persist it. Is that right?